# Get list of registered Pending Intents in Android OS

Tags: android

I register alarms which I schedule to execute at given time, and it can be many alarms depending on the size of the scheduled list. But I have two questions which remains unclear to me:

1) How can I query the OS for the Pending Intents I registers? I need this for testing. The psudo code for what I want would be something like this:

```
List<PendingIntent> intentsInOS = context.getAllPendingIntentsOfType(AppConstants.INTENT_ALARM_SCHEDULE));
```

2) See the pending intent I create, I provide an action and extra data (the schedule id).

```
private Intent getSchedeuleIntent(Integer id) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(AppConstants.INTENT_ALARM_SCHEDULE);
    intent.putExtra(AppConstants.INTENT_ALARM_SCHEDULE_EXTRA, id);

    return intent;
}
```

But we also say that the intent have FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT. Will it cancel all pending intents with same action, or does it have to both same action AND extra data?

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, getSchedeuleIntent(schedule.id), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

My code

```
@Override
public void run() {

    List<ScheduledLocation> schedules = dbManager.getScheduledLocations();
    if(schedules == null || schedules.isEmpty()){
        return;
    }

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    //alarmManager.

    // we need to get the number of milliseconds from current time till next hour:minute the next day.
    for(ScheduledLocation schedule : schedules){

        long triggerAtMillis = DateUtils.millisecondsBetweenNowAndNext(now, schedule.hour, schedule.minute, schedule.day);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, getSchedeuleIntent(schedule.id), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, MILLISECONDS_IN_WEEK, pendingIntent);
    }

    // List<PendingIntent> intentsInOS = context.getAllPendingIntentsOfType(AppConstants.INTENT_ALARM_SCHEDULE));

}


private Intent getSchedeuleIntent(Integer id) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(AppConstants.INTENT_ALARM_SCHEDULE);
    intent.putExtra(AppConstants.INTENT_ALARM_SCHEDULE_EXTRA, id);

    return intent;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### 1 How can I query the OS for the Pending Intents I registers?

I'm not sure you can, but you can check if a specific `PendingIntent` is registered or not like this :

```
private boolean checkIfPendingIntentIsRegistered() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, RingReceiver.class);
    // Build the exact same pending intent you want to check.
    // Everything has to match except extras.
    return (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
}
```

### 2 Will it cancel all pending intents with same action, or does it have to both same action AND extra data?

It will cancel all the `PendingIntent` that are resolved to be equal.

What exactly does **equal** means ?

The java doc of android says:

> Determine if two intents are the same for the purposes of intent
>   resolution (filtering). That is, if their action, data, type, class,
>   and categories are the same.  This does *not* compare any extra
>   data included in the intents.

You can read at the 7391 line here : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/Intent.java

To sum up, all `PendingIntent` that are build exactly the same except extras will be cancelled.