# Android: why are old PendingIntents not deleted unless I reboot or manually uninstall the app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

## Some background

I have an app that has an ongoing notification.  I use `NotificationCompat.Builder` to create the notification.  I call `setContentIntent()` on the builder to add a `PendingIntent` to the notification, so that MyActivity runs when I click on the notification.

When MyActivity is running, and I click on the ongoing notification, I want MyActivity's `onNewIntent()` to be called.  In order to achieve this, I set MyActivity's launchMode to "singleTask", and the PendingIntent I pass to `setContentIntent()` is created like this:

```
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent( this,
                                  MyActivity.class );
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this,
                                                         REQUEST_CODE,
                                                         notifyIntent,
                                                         PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
```

I debug my app in IntelliJ, and I see everything working as expected.  Nothing weird so far.

## The problem

It gets weird when I try to switch the PendingIntent to one that is created using `TaskStackBuilder`.  I know that this will no longer cause `onNewIntent()` to be called, just bear with me:

```
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent( this,
                                  MyActivity.class );
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create( this );
stackBuilder.addParentStack( MyActivity.class );
stackBuilder.addNextIntent( notifyIntent );
PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent( REQUEST_CODE,
                                                             PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
```

So let's say I've updated my PendingIntent to be created this way.  I hit ctrl+S to save my file.  I hit the debug button again, which rebuilds the app, replaces the old apk etc on my device, and begins debugging.  What I expect to see now when I click the ongoing notification is that the existing running MyActivity is destroyed and a new one is created, i.e., `onCreate()` is called.  But, I don't see that.  Instead, I still see `onNewIntent()` get called as before, as if I hadn't saved my code and rebuilt it.

Hmm, but I definitely did save it and rebuild it, because other changes in the same file, such as a new Toast, are showing up.

Let me reboot my device and retry.  Huh, now `onCreate()` is getting called instead of `onNewIntent()`.  Why does it work only after rebooting?

I have tried this on different devices and emulators.  I tried another IDE.  Same thing.

I've even tried going back from using the TaskStackBuilder to the original PendingIntent, and I still get unexpected behavior.  In other words, I would expect to see `onNewIntent()` to get called since I am no longer using TaskStackBuilder, but I see `onCreate()` get called instead.

So, if I reboot my device, then the correct, expected behavior occurs.  Manually uninstalling the app also yields the correct, expected behavior.

Am I missing something totally obvious?  Why does this happen?  It's as if Android is remembering old PendingIntent from the previous debug session.

## To reproduce

I created a toy example from the sample code here:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Here's the toy example:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.blah.pendingintent.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 2;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private NotificationCompat.Builder m_builder;
    private NotificationManager m_notificationMgr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

        m_builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this );
        m_notificationMgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent( Intent intent )
    {
        super.onNewIntent( intent );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onClick( View v )
    {
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent( this,
                                          MainActivity.class );

        // comment out one of these lines and rerun
        PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent = getPendingIntentWithActivity( notifyIntent );
        // PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent = getPendingIntentWithBackStack( notifyIntent );

        m_builder.setContentIntent( notifyPendingIntent );

        m_builder.setContentTitle( "Picture Download" )
                 .setContentText( "Download in progress" )
                 .setSmallIcon( R.drawable.abc_ic_go );

        new Thread( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                int incr;
                for ( incr = 0; incr <= 100; incr += 5 )
                {
                    m_builder.setProgress( 0,
                                           0,
                                           true );
                    m_notificationMgr.notify( NOTIFICATION_ID,
                                              m_builder.build() );
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep( 5 * 1000 );
                    }
                    catch ( InterruptedException e )
                    {
                        Log.d( TAG,
                               "sleep failure" );
                    }
                }
                m_builder.setContentText( "Download complete" )
                        .setProgress( 0,
                                      0,
                                      false );
                m_notificationMgr.notify( NOTIFICATION_ID,
                                          m_builder.build() );
            }
        }

        ).start();
    }

    private PendingIntent getPendingIntentWithBackStack( Intent notifyIntent )
    {
        Toast.makeText( this,
                        "Using TaskStackBuilder",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG )
             .show();
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create( this );
        stackBuilder.addParentStack( MainActivity.class );
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent( notifyIntent );
        return stackBuilder.getPendingIntent( REQUEST_CODE,
                                              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
    }

    private PendingIntent getPendingIntentWithActivity( Intent notifyIntent )
    {
        Toast.makeText( this,
                        "Using PendingIntent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG )
             .show();
        return PendingIntent.getActivity( this,
                                          REQUEST_CODE,
                                          notifyIntent,
                                          PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="pres butan"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.blah.pendingintent.example" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.blah.pendingintent.example.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle** (default file from the IntelliJ wizard)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 18
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, if I reboot my device, then the correct, expected behavior occurs.
>   Manually uninstalling the app also yields the correct, expected
>   behavior.

The reason is, when you debug the app without uninstalling it, the previously created `PendingIntent`s are still with the `AlarmManager`. When you uninstall the app completely, the previous `PendingIntent`s are destroyed. Rebooting the phone also destroys all existing `PendingIntent`s.

> It's as if Android is remembering old PendingIntent from the previous
>   debug session.

That is *exactly* what is happening. So when you test apps that make use of `PendingIntent`s, you should ALWAYS uninstall the app first and re-run it from your IDE to produce the correct, expected behavior. Note also that, as you have observed, existing `PendingIntent`s are destroyed when you reboot the phone. So your app will have to programmatically recreate the `PendingIntent`s that get destroyed on reboot (so that if the user of your app reboots his phone, they get back the alarms they scheduled). This is done by intercepting the `BOOT_COMPLETE` event. See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#boot) for more on this.

**EDIT:**

To programmatically check whether a previously created `PendingIntent` exists or not, use this:

```
boolean pendingIntentExists = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, 
                               intent, 
                               PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

where `requestCode` and `intent` must be the same as when you previously created this `PendingIntent`.

I hope that answers your question.

**EDIT 2:**

I believe in your case, the test for checking the existence of a `PendingIntent` needs to be:

```
// check PendingIntent for Activity
boolean pendingIntentExists = (PendingIntent.getActivity( this,
                                      REQUEST_CODE,
                                      notifyIntent,
                                      PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

// check PendingIntent for backstack
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create( this );
    stackBuilder.addParentStack( MainActivity.class );
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent( notifyIntent );
    boolean pendingIntentExists = (stackBuilder.getPendingIntent( REQUEST_CODE,
                                          PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE ) != null);
```

Please try this.

Comment: @kevin: was this useful ?

Comment: yes, it was useful, thank you!  I am just trying to verify that the old PendingIntent exists by doing a `getBroadcast()` on it (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13292412) immediately after creating the Intent, but it's coming up null for me.  Is this a reasonable approach?  Should I be doing something else to verify the existence of an old PendingIntent?

Comment: yes I've tried it.  Like I said, it always comes up null, but maybe I'm doing it wrong.  In the above toy example, I call `getBroadcast()` after the line where notifyIntent is first created at the top of `onClick()`.  I run the app, and the result of `getBroadcast()` is null, as expected.  Then I run the app again, but the result is again null.  Is this what you see when you run the toy example?

Comment: I just tried EDIT 2.  Thanks for following up on this, btw.  Anyway what I found is that getting the pending intent from the task stack builder will return non-null for either way of creating the pending intent.  However, using `getBroadcast()` will return null for either way of creating the pending intent, so I'm not sure that that's appropriate for determining whether there's an existing pending intent.  I do see that, using the other method, there's a pending intent hanging around, so I'm good with this.  Thanks again!